# How to get MATLAB's prefdir from the OS's command line?

Tags: matlab

How can a script running outside of MATLAB find out the value returned (by default) by MATLAB's `prefdir()`?  I'm interested in ways to do this both under Windows and under Unix-type OS's.

---

Update: FWIW, by trial-and-error, I found this monstrosity for Darwin:

```
% /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/matlab \
    -nojvm -nodesktop -nodisplay -nosplash \
    -r "fprintf('OUTPUT: %s\n', prefdir); quit;" 2>&1 | \
    perl -ne 'print if s/^OUTPUT: //'
/Users/yourstruly/.matlab/R2014a
```

(This is, of course, an embarrassment.  I sincerely hope there's something better.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the biggest problem on Windows is that when you start bare MatLab Command window (with all the switched you use) it prints everything to itself and you can not intercept this output (at least without WinAPI).
Consider writing `prefdir` to temporary file:

```
matlab ^
-nojvm ^
-nodesktop ^
-nodisplay ^
-nosplash ^
-r "f=fopen('prefdir.txt','w');fprintf(f,'%s\n',prefdir);fclose(f);quit;" ^
2>&1
```

here `^` does the same thing as backslash in your example (it should be last character in the line to work).
If you write this code as a single line it might work on all machines assuming that `matlab/bin` folder is added to path environment variable.

By the way, why you print "OUTPUT:" and then remove it with Perl?
Also Perl is rarely found on windows machines if this is not programmer's machine :)

Comment: If you have MATLAB, you automatically have Perl, as it's included with a MATLAB installation.

Comment: @SamRoberts, Yes, I know. But I installed "MatLab R2013a 64bit" on Win7-64 and it added only `C:\MATLAB\R2013a\runtime\win64` and `C:\MATLAB\R2013a\bin` to system PATH variable while Perl binaries are in `C:\MATLAB\R2013a\sys\perl\win32\bin`. This is strange because 64-bit version of MatLab may also include 64-bit version of Perl.